# MariaDB *.myi files don't appear in files manager

Tags: mysql, mariadb

**I'm working with `maria-db` on backing up my db**
the server's OS is `Microsoft Server 2012` and my machine is `Windows 7`.

I'm following the copy-paste approach, for some reason I can't find some of my `*.MYI` and `*.MYD` files, but the db works fine on the server, so this means the the files exist!

Is there any way to locate the files?

Comment: Yeah, do a file search - although this is impossible to answer as you don't say which OS you're on

Comment: windows 7 ,  sorry

Comment: I want to copy files from Windows server 2012 to windows 7

Comment: There is no such thing as a copy paste approach....

Comment: Perhaps your tables are InnoDB, not MyISAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows, in its infinite wisdom, tries to protect the user from himself.  Those files are "hidden".  Go into the File Mangler and grant yourself permission to see hidden files.

You can copy the *entire* msyql tree from one machine to another -- *if* the version on the new machine is not "too different".  What version of MySQL are you coming from and going to?

Check to see whether your tables are `ENGINE=MyISAM` (which uses `.MYD` and `.MYI` files) and not InnoDB.  Or simply search for `*.frm` files which exist for both.

You can also get a clue of where things are by doing

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%dir%';
```